# Does using a snapshot of running PID on Linux provide enough entropy?

Tags: randomness, entropy, pseudo-random-generator

I am thinking about running the following linux command on each boot to generate a new random token each boot.

```
printf '%s' "$RANDOM"`ps -e` | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

- The first part takes a string from the shell's `$RANDOM` variable and then from `ps -e` snapshot of every running process and PID at the moment.
- The second hashes the string.
- The last part simply cleans up the string by removing the trailing space-dash outputted with the hash.

**Is this enough to generate a quick random string with enough entropy?**

Comment: Enough entropy for what? Why not just use `/dev/urandom`?

Comment: Neither $RANDOM nor PIDs are a cryptographically secure source of random numbers.

Comment: What are you using the string for?  You say "random token" but don't explain the attributes of the token.  In any case, this looks like a very weak source of entropy, one I wouldn't recommend for security purposes. As @bkjvbx said, just use /dev/urandom, which is exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thanks. Is `$RANDOM` weaker than `/dev/urandom`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't; not unless you want to have $2^{15}$ bits of non-cryptographically secure random token - the output of the `$RANDOM` function of bash.

How PID's are created depends on the operating system. The only other information is the starting time really. Neither of those can be seen as random and is easy to guess and even to influence.

There have been some proposed patches to make PID's more random in Linux but they were rejected by the kernel maintainers. They are kind of chicken-egg anyway; to create random ID's the kernel would need to have a good random number generator which you could employ yourself.

Comment: Relying on bash during boot time is horrific as well, in my opinion.

Comment: So would using `/dev/urandom` be better or `$RANDOM` would be better?

Comment: `/dev/urandom` absolutely would trump `$RANDOM` when it comes to cryptography.